# Decision Tree in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Instead of having to deal with Excel Shapes, I'm trying to do a VBA script where I can just type out the decision tree entries. Each branch is a quantity of time. At the end of each path is the sum total of each path. I press play in VBA trying both sets of code and nothing happens in excel worksheets:

I have 2 attempts:

```
 Sub CreateDecisionTree()
 
 'Declare variables
 Dim objExcel As Excel.Application Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
 Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet Dim objShape As Excel.Shape 
 Dim totalDays As Integer 'Variable to store the total number of days
 
 'Create an Excel application object 
 Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
 
 'Add a new workbook 
 Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
 
 'Add a new worksheet 
 Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets.Add
 
 'Add the first decision point shape 
 Set objShape = objWorksheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 50, 50, 50, 50)
 objShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Decision Point 1 (1 day)"
 totalDays = totalDays + 1
 
 'Add the second decision point shape Set objShape =
 objWorksheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 200, 50, 50, 50)
 objShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Decision Point 2 (1 day)"
 totalDays = totalDays + 1
 
 'Connect the decision point shapes with a line Set objShape =
 objWorksheet.Shapes.AddLine(75, 75, 225, 75)
 
 'Add the third decision point shape Set objShape =
 objWorksheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 350, 50, 50, 50)
 objShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Decision Point 3 (1 day)"
 totalDays = totalDays + 1
 
 'Connect the decision point shapes with a line Set objShape =
 objWorksheet.Shapes.AddLine(375, 75, 375, 175)
 
 End Sub
```

and

```
 Sub CreateTOCTree()
 
 'Declare variables 
 Dim objExcel As Excel.Application Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook 
 Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet Dim objShape As Excel.Shape
 
 'Create an Excel application object 
 Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
 
 'Add a new workbook 
 Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
 
 'Add a new worksheet 
 Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets.Add
 
 'Add the first decision point shape 
 Set objShape = objWorksheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 50, 50, 50, 50)
 objShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Decision Point 1"
 
 'Add the second decision point shape
 Set objShape = objWorksheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 200, 50, 50, 50)
 objShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Decision Point 2"
 
 'Connect the decision point shapes with a line
 Set objShape = objWorksheet.Shapes.AddLine(75, 75, 225, 75)
 
 'Add the third decision point shape
 Set objShape = objWorksheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 350, 50, 50, 50)
 objShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Decision Point 3"
 
 'Check if Excel application object was created successfully
 If objExcel Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Excel application object could not be created."
     Exit Sub End If
 
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

New Excel Applications are opened with `Applicaton.Visible = False` by default. Set `objExcel.Visible = True` if you want the user to see the new window.